# creación desencadenadores para delete en sql server

Tags: sql

¿Dónde se crean los triggers para delete? ¿en procedimientos almacenados? ¿vistas?

Nunca hice ninguno.

Uso sql server 2017.

Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Abres una ventana de editor de consultas y escribes la definición del desencadenador empezando por `CREATE TRIGGER`

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un desencadenador o trigger (dependiendo el idioma del SQL Server) puedes hacerlo de 2 formas: desde la interfaz del SQL Server expandes el símbolo de (+) donde verás una carpeta que dice Triggers y le das click derecho y seleccionas New Trigger.
Otra forma de crear el trigger es por consulta:

```
CREATE TRIGGER nombre_trigger
ON nombre_tabla
AFTER  {[INSERT],[UPDATE],[DELETE]} --segun sea tu caso
AS
--Aca indicas tus consultas
END
```

Agradecería tu respuesta. Saludos!